# How to make consumer resilient with RabbitMQ?

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq

I want to make consumer resilient that is when rabbitmq fails or some failure i want it to retry in .net core/standard 2.1. is there any documentation/ steps you can point me too or ideas to start this ?

Comment: That article is recommended https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2018/8/31/rabbitmq-vs-kafka-part-5-fault-tolerance-and-high-availability-with-rabbitmq

Comment: This might be of help: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

Answer (score 3):

Recovering connections is [clearly documented](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#recovery) and supported by the .NET client.